# Is there a keyboard shortcut to view all open documents in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, shortcut

I am trying to learn the keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio in order to be more productive.  So I downloaded a document showing many of the default keybindings in Visual Basic when using the VS 2008 IDE from [Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255b8cf1-f6bd-4b55-bb42-dd1a69315833&displaylang=en)

When I tried what they say is the keyboard shortcut to view all open documents (**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd>**), I got a completely unexpected result on my XP machine; my entire screen display was flipped upside down!

Was this a prank by someone at Microsoft? I can't imagine what practical value this flipping of the screen would have.

Does anyone know what the *correct* keyboard shortcut is to view all open documents in VS 2008?

Oh and if you try the above shortcut and it flips your display the way it did mine, do a **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd>** to switch it back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a conflict between your graphics driver and Visual Studio. Go to your driver settings page (Control panel) and disable the display rotation shortcuts. With this conflict removed, the shortcut will work in Visual Studio.